# Error in my code when trying to storeData

Tags: ios, swift

I get

> Referencing instance method 'encode' on 'Array' requires that '(item: String?, price: String?, salesPrice: String?)' conform to 'Encodable' "

this error in the `storeData()` function. Did I even save the tuple correctly in user defaults? If anyone can help that would be great!Any help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit

let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.Saving.Data")

struct Product: Codable {
    var title: String
    var price: String
    var salePrice: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items: [(item: String?, price: String?, salesPrice: String?)] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        getData()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        storeData()
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addTextField { (itemTF) in
                itemTF.placeholder = "Item"
            }

            alert.addTextField { (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "Price"
            }

            alert.addTextField { (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "Sale Price"
            }

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in

                var product : (item: String, price: String, salesPrice: String) = ("","","")

                if let textField1 = alert.textFields?[0], let text = textField1.text {
                    print(text)
                    product.item = text

                }

                if let textField2 = alert.textFields?[1], let text = textField2.text {
                    print(text)
                     product.price = text

                }

                if let textField3 = alert.textFields?[2], let text = textField3.text {
                    print(text)
                    product.salesPrice = text

                }
                self.add(product)
            }

            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true)
            storeData()
        }

       func add(_ product: (item: String, price: String, salesPrice: String)) {
            let index = 0
            items.insert(product, at: index)

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            storeData()
        }


     func storeData() {

           if let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "savedData")

           }
       }

       func getData() {

        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedData") {
            let items = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
            print(items)
           }
       }



}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let product = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = product.item
        print(product.price ?? "")
        print(product.salesPrice ?? "")

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
        storeData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a tuple in your array when you have a struct with the same properties? I would suggest using the struct instead and make it conform to Codable

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(item: String, price: String, salesPrice: String)' to expected argument type 'Product' i get this in the add function when i change var items = [(items:...ect to var items = [Product]()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments it's incomprehensible why you use an extra tuple with the same design as your struct `Product`. This causes your problems.

So get rid of the tuple.

Declare `items`

```
var items = [Product]()
```

Replace the alert action with

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in

    let item = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
    let price = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
    let salesPrice = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""

    let product = Product(item: item, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice)
    self.addProduct(product)
}
```

Replace `add` with

```
  func addProduct(_ product: Product) {
        let index = 0
        items.insert(product, at: index)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        storeData()
    }
```

Replace `getData` with

```
func getData() {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedData") {
        do {
            items = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
            print(items)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
}
```

Side note: Be aware that the code saves the data in *standard* `UserDefaults`, not in your custom suite.

And finally – not related to the issue – to get a nice animation in `tableView:commit editingStyle:` replace

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

with

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: i get this error in addButtonTapped Use of unresolved identifier 'alert'

Comment: This is only the **action**. Of course you have to keep the lines to create the alert controller and to add the text fields.

Comment: I get this error in cellForRowAt. "   Cannot assign value of type 'Product' to type 'String?'  " @vadian

Comment: You are assigning `product` to the label (and you changed the code in the question). This is wrong. You have to assign one of the properties to the label for example `cell.textLabel?.text = product.title`. And reuse cells, `let cell = UITableViewCell()` is inappropriate.